# How to call R from within a web server (like Apache)?

Tags: apache, r, embedded-language

That is, is there an embedded R interpreter available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use Jeff Horner's excellent [**rapache**](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rapache/).

Other options that are CGI-alike are mentioned in the [section 4 of the R FAQ which discusses Web interfaces](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#R-Web-Interfaces).

Answer (score 3):

You can used Shiny app into R
http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/