# Calling R from apache web server

Tags: r, apache

I am new to R. I am trying to call 'R' from a webserver created using apache. For this purpose I have written a perl script which calls the R from within it.  Everything works fine until the 'R' program is called, and it gives the error in the error.log file as :
"Command 'R' not found in /sbin, /usr/sbin, /bin, /usr/bin at /usr/local/share/perl5/Statistics/R.pm line 332."
Is there any problem with the environment variables for R (if any) or is there something else which i am not able to understand. Though I found a similar question here which gave the solution of using rapache but i am not sure whether i can use it or not.  Any sort of help will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the path within the perl script or using the full pathname to R?  In addition, since you say, "I found a similar question here," please link to it.

Comment: Yes, I had tried the same but the problem still persisted. And the link for the similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395174/how-to-call-r-from-within-a-web-server-like-apache

Comment: Show us your perl code that calls R. It looks like you are using a perl package (Statistics:R) but haven't configured it to find R properly.

Comment: Hi..yes that was the problem..! Since i was using it for the first time i could not rightly configure it to find R. Just got it right yesterday.  Thanks for the suggestion.1 :)